# Что я делаю не так при создании свойства зависимости в wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть у меня файл MainWindow.XAML
- в котором я создаю собственный элемент управления с именем ControlBrush

```
<ControlBrush:MyBrushClass
        x:Name="NewBackground"
          CanvasBrushCLR="{Binding ElementName=canvas1, Path=Background }">

    </ControlBrush:MyBrushClass>
```

используя класс MyBrushClass 
вот я его подключаю:

```
xmlns:ControlBrush="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
```

Задаю этому элементу управления имя x:Name="NewBackground"
Далее обращаюсь к CLR свойству CanvasBrushCLR
вот оно в классе MyBrushClass :

```
public double CanvasBrushCLR
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(CanvasBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CanvasBrushProperty, value); }
    }
```

и в качестве значения использую привязку (Binding) к элементу canvas1 на форме и его свойству Background

Что касается CLR свойства, которое я использую для привязки, оно у меня используется при регистрации свойства зависимости CanvasBrushProperty

```
       public static DependencyProperty CanvasBrushProperty;//имя поля
      static MyBrushClass()
    {
        CanvasBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CanvasBrushCLR", typeof(double ), typeof(MyBrushClass));
    }
        //CanvasBrushCLR -ИМЯ CLR обвертки 
        //typeof(Color) - тип свойства зависимости
        //typeof(MyBrushClass) - класс в котором регистрируется свойство зависимости
```

Ну и на форме у меня есть две кнопки и соответственно обработчики событий для них:

```
MyBrushClass mb;
    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

      mb = new MyBrushClass();
      canvas1.Background.Opacity =  mb.CanvasBrushCLR; //обрабатываем binding

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mb = new MyBrushClass();
        mb.CanvasBrushCLR = (double)Convert.ToInt32( TB1.GetLineText(0));
    }
```

Как видно в одном из обработчиков событий я в CLR свойство записываю значение из TB1 - TextBox на форме - т.е я ввожу строку в TextBox , и по нажатию на кнопку она преобразуется в double и присваивается свойству CanvasBrushCLR.
Но, когда в другой кнопке я хочу уже "проинициализированным" свойством CanvasBrushCLR присвоить canvas1.Background.Opacity у меня появляется ошибка:

> Не удается задать свойство объекта "#FFFFFFFF", так как он находится в состоянии "только чтение

**- хотя и Opacity и CanvasBrushCLR - имеют методы доступа get и set**

*Специально так подробно рассматриваю, что бы продемонстрировать, что вроде бы разобрался в свойствах зависимости - т.е примерно имею представление, но до конца не могу понять где ошибка.*
Полный код:

- MainWindowXAML

  ```
  mc:Ignorable="d"

  Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded"   >
  ```

  ```
  </ControlBrush:MyBrushClass>
  <InkCanvas x:Name="canvas1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0.4,-9.2"  />

  <TextBox x:Name="TB1"></TextBox>
  <DockPanel  LastChildFill="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,0,0.4,0" >
      <Border
          DockPanel.Dock="Right"
          Background="Transparent"
      MouseMove="Border_MouseEnter"
      MouseLeave="Border_MouseLeave"
     >
          <Button x:Name="Button"
          Background="Gray"
          Content="Menu" 
          Height="Auto"/>

      </Border>

  </DockPanel>
  <Button x:Name="button1" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto"  Margin="20.2,0,47.2,0" Grid.Column="1"
          Content="получить значение " Click="button1_Click"></Button>
  <Button x:Name="button2" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto"  Margin="60.8,0,18.4,0" Grid.Column="2"
          Content="присвоить значение" Click="button2_Click"></Button>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="5*"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="173*">

      </ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="158*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="187*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="98*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  ```

- MyBrushClass

  ```
          using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Linq;
          using System.Text;
      using System.Threading.Tasks;
      using System.Windows;
     using System.Windows.Controls;
       using System.Windows.Media;

       namespace WpfApp1
    {
      public  class MyBrushClass : InkCanvas
      {
         public static DependencyProperty CanvasBrushProperty;//имя поля
         static MyBrushClass()
         {
             CanvasBrushProperty = 
         DependencyProperty.Register("CanvasBrushCLR", typeof(double ), 
     typeof(MyBrushClass));
         }
            //CanvasBrushCLR -ИМЯ CLR обвертки 
            //typeof(Color) - тип свойства зависимости
            //typeof(MyBrushClass) - класс в котором регистрируется свойсво 
              зависимости

          //Регистрируем CLR обвертку
           public double CanvasBrushCLR
      {
          get { return (double)GetValue(CanvasBrushProperty); }
          set { SetValue(CanvasBrushProperty, value); }
      }
  }
  ```

  }
- MainWindowXAML.CS

  ```
  using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
     using System.Windows.Controls;
     using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
  using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
     using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
  using System.Windows.Navigation;
       using System.Windows.Shapes;

      namespace WpfApp1
      {
     /// <summary>
       /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
         /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
       {


  public static InkCanvas inkCan;
  public MainWindow()
  {
      InitializeComponent();

  }

  private void Border_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
      Button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
  }

  private void Border_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
      Button.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
  }
  MyBrushClass mb;
  private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {

    mb = new MyBrushClass();
    canvas1.Background.Opacity =  mb.CanvasBrushCLR;//потому что Binding //обрабатываем binding

  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      mb = new MyBrushClass();
      mb.CanvasBrushCLR = (double)Convert.ToInt32( TB1.GetLineText(0));
  }

  private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {

   }
  }
   }
  ```

Comment: Приведите полный код вашего элемента управления плюс код главного окна, на котором расположен элемент, по обрывкам сложно понять что  происходит.

Comment: Добавил полный код. Извините что так поздно - раньше не мог - зашел на сайт только сейчас.

Comment: Извините за оффтопик — а у вас в исходниках тоже вот такое же форматирование? Там, каждый `using` с другим отступом?

Comment: @VladD, ну лесенкой же красивее

Comment: Не специально, просто кода вставляю "красивым" форматированием как у меня в студии - редактор кода на Stack Overflow не хочет воспринимать его как код - решение нашел именно такое, необходимо  "отодвинуть строку в сторону " - что я и делаю пробелами.

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали

> canvas1.Background у вас равен Brushes.White. Это синглтон, и он находится в состоянии Frozen (свойство IsFrozen == true), то есть его нельзя менять. Попробуйте указать "#FFFFFF" вместо "White".

-работает

Comment: Ваша проблема решилась?